# How do I trim whitespace, but not newlines, from subshell output in bash?

Tags: bash, whitespace, tr

There are many tens, maybe a hundred or more previous questions that seem "identical" to this already here, but after extensive search, I found NOTHING that even came close to working - though I did learn quite a lot - and so I decided to just RTFM and figure this out on my own.

**The Problem**

I wanted to search the output of a `ps auxwww` command to find processes of interest, and the issue was that I can't just simply use `cut` to find the exact data from them that I wanted. `ps`, it turns out, tries to columnate the output, adding either extra spaces or tabs that get in the way of using cut to get the correct data.

So, since I'm not a master at bash, I did a search... The answers I found were all focused on either variables - a "backup strategy" from my point of view that itself didn't solve the whole problem - or they only trimmed leading or trailing space or all "whitespace" including newlines. NOPE, Won't Work For Cut! And, neither will removing trailing newlines and so forth.

So, restated, the question is, how do we efficiently end up with the white space defined as simply a single space between other characters without eliminating newlines?

Below, I will give my answer, but I welcome others to give theirs - who knows, maybe someone has a better answer?!

Comment: `ps auxwww | tr -s [:space:]` to "squeeze" all whitespace between columns to a single space.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Too bad you hadn't provided this answer previously because I could have used it and saved me a LOT of time; if you read the answer I provided you'll see that's almost exactly what I did.

Comment: Yep, I saw that after I dropped the "squeeze" comment. Good job having the "sticktoitiveness" to find a solution on your own.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

At least MY answer - please leave your own, too! - was to do this:

```
ps auxwww | grep <program> | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d ' ' -f <field_of_interest>
```

This worked great!

Obviously, there are many ways to adapt this to other needs.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking, though I would suggest `awk` to do it all in a single process. `awk` is the swiss-army knife of text process. If you are just getting started, know time spent learning `awk` will be saved 10-fold going forward. (`awk`, which isn't bad after you figure out it just reads a line at a time and applies the rules you write in order) [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great reference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, thanks; please provide your own answer! I'm sure there are many to this problem and we need MORE about this here on this site - at least, that's my view. (I read so many "answers" that didn't work...)

Comment: You could do `awk -v prog="program" '{/prog/ { print $<field_of_interest> }' < <(ps auxwww)` which uses *process substitution* (bash only) to feed the output to the `awk` command. You can provide `program` as a shell variable, e.g. if you had it stored in `p` it would be `-v prog="$p" ...`. You can do the same for `<field_of_interest>`, just add another `-v fnum="field_of_interest"` and then it simplifies to `print $fnum`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ... Rather than just leaving your ideas in a comment, how about providing an alternative answer?

Comment: Ok, give me a sec. and I write it up. You have any particular `<field_of_interest>` that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to all of the pipes and `grep` with `cut`, you could simply use `awk`. The benefit of using `awk`with the default field-separator (`FS`) being set to break on whitespace is that it considers any number of whitespace between fields as a single separator.

So using `awk` will do away with needing to use `tr -s` to "squeeze" whitespace to define fields. Further, `awk` gives far greater control over field matching using regular expressions rather than having to rely on `grep` of a full line and  `cut` to locate a pre-determined field numbers. (though to some extent you will still have to tell `awk` what field out of the `ps` command you are interested in)

Using bash, you can also eliminate the pipe `|` by using *process substitution* to send the output of `ps auxwww` to `awk` on `stdin` using redirection, e.g. `awk ... < <(ps auxwww)` for a single tidy command line.

To get your `"program"` and `"file_of_interest"` into `awk` you have two options. You can initialize `awk` variables using the `-v var=value` option (there can be multiple `-v` otions given), or you can use the `BEGIN` rule to initialize the variables. The only difference being with `-v` you can provide a shell variable for `value` and there is no whitespace allowed surrounding the `=` sign, while within `BEGIN` any whitespace is ignored.

So in your case a couple of examples to get the virtual memory size for `firefox` processes, you could use:

```
awk -v prog="firefox" -v fnum="5" '
    $11 ~ prog {print $fnum}
' < <(ps auxwww)
```

(above if you had `myprog=firefox` as a shell variable, you could use `-v prog="$myprog"` to initialize the `prog` variable for `awk`)

or using the `BEGIN` rule, you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {prog = "firefox"; fnum = "5"}
    $11 ~ prog {print $fnum }
' < <(ps auxwww)
```

In each command above, it locates the `COMMAND` field from `ps` (field 11) and checks whether it contains `firefox` and if so it outputs field no. 5 the virtual memory size used by each process.

Both work fine as one-liners as well, e.g.

```
awk -v prog="firefox" -v fnum="5" '$11 ~ prog {print $fnum}' < <(ps auxwww)
```

Don't get me wrong, the pipeline is perfectly fine, it will just be slow. For short commands with limited output there won't be much difference, but when the output is large, `awk` will provide orders of magnitude improvement over having to `tr` and `grep` and `cut` reading over the same records three times.

The reason being, the pipes and the process on each side requires separate processes be spawned by the shell. So minimizes their use, improves the efficiency of what your script is doing. Now if the data is small as are the processes, there isn't much of a difference. However if you are reading a 3G file 3 times over -- that's is the difference in orders of magnitude. Hours verses minutes or seconds.

Comment: Simple question: Why do you feel pipes are such a problem?

Comment: The pipes and the process on each side requires separate processes be spawned by the shell. So minimizes their use, improves the efficiency of what your script is doing. Now if the data is small as are the processes, there isn't much of a difference. However if you are reading a 3G file 3 times over -- that's is the difference in orders of magnitude. Hours verses minutes or seconds.

Comment: I recommend that be part of an answer and not left to comments! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use single quotes on CentosOS Linux to get `tr` working like described above:

```
ps -o ppid= $$ | tr -d '[:space:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of pipes using this Perl one-liner, which uses Perl regexes instead of a separate `grep` process. This combines `grep`, `tr` and `cut` in a single command, with an easy way to manipulate the output (`@F` is the array of fields, 0-indexed):

Examples:

```
# Start an example process to provide the input for `ps` in the next commands:
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_14 --geometry 109x65 /tmp/foo &

# Print single space-delimited output of `ps` for all emacs processes:
ps auxwww | perl -lane 'print "@F" if $F[10] =~ /emacs/i'

# Prints:
# bar 72144 0.0 0.5 4610272 82320 s006 SN 11:15AM 0:01.31 /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_14 --geometry 109x65 /tmp/foo

# Print emacs PID and file name opened with emacs:

ps auxwww | perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[1, -1] if $F[10] =~ /emacs/i'

# Prints:
# 72144   /tmp/foo
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)